# how to share data between groovy files?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have one common groovy file that contains few const variables and functions...
and I also have more groovy files with pipelineJob that use the variables and functions from the common file
what is the best way to import all the data from the common file to the other files?

Comment: have you seen these questions?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753874/how-to-use-multiple-classes-in-multiple-files-in-scripts
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136328/including-a-groovy-script-in-another-groovy
and this blog post could also be helpful: http://ikoodi.nl/2012/05/14/groovy-scripting-using-multiple-files/

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this with Jenkins, but if Jenkins executes the Groovy script as if by invoking `groovy -cp .... myScript.groovy` it should work:

`utils.groovy`:

```
// notice there's no "def", otherwise the def would be local only
name = 'Joe'

class MyUtils {
    static String greeting(String name) {
        "Hello $name"
    }
}
```

`src/main.groovy`

```
def shell = new GroovyShell(getBinding())
shell.evaluate(new File('utils.groovy'))

println MyUtils.greeting(name)
```

Running it:

```
$ groovy src/Main.groovy
Hello Joe
```

Because the `Script` base class by default also has an `evaluate` method, your can actually just call that instead of using a `GroovyShell` and the result should be identical:

`src/main.groovy`

```
evaluate(new File('utils.groovy'))

println MyUtils.greeting(name)
```

If it doesn't work it's because the `Script` base class has been changed , probably... the first approach should work in all cases.